# Deep copy of SQLAlchemy object with association_proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to deepcopy an object instance of an SQLAlchemy class which contains an association_proxy?

When deepcopying an instance of this class for example

```
class Device(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'collect_inventory'

    _id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    _ip = Column('ip', String(15), index=True)

    fields = association_proxy("field_values", "value",
                               creator=lambda k, v:
                                       FieldValue(field=k, value=v)
                              )
```

I receive this error:

```
  File "/opt/secadvisor/lib/component.py", line 198, in _deliver_mods
    receiver.receive(copy.deepcopy(data), msg_type, module_name, component)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 189, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 338, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 162, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 255, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 162, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 235, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 189, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 338, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 162, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 255, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 189, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy.py", line 323, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: attrgetter expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

The error only occurs, when accessing the association_proxy field (`fields` in this case).

Comment: `The AssociationProxy object produced by the association_proxy() function is an instance of a Python descriptor.` from [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html). You might want to check and see if descriptors have problems with `deepcopy`ing.

Comment: Thank's for advice, but I did not find anything. Might this be a bug in Python/SQLAlchemy or does it work like designed?

Comment: I don't think it *should* be like this. If it is a bug, it's in SQLAlchemy not in Python. Probably, there's a `__deepcopy__` missing (not defined) somewhere probably or something...